# Allow all ports to connect to docDB from DMS?

Tags: aws-dms, aws-documentdb

While trying to create a target endpoint for documentDB, I have to edit the security setting and allow "All traffic" to "anywhere". If I do not follow this step, the DMS instance is not be able to connect to the DocumentDB cluster.
Opening all ports is insecure for obvious reasons. What is the correct setting that needs to be changed in VPC security group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security group that governs your DocumentDB cluster (source) needs to allow inbound connections on port 27017 (default port) from the security group for your DMS task.

Comment: Your answer is correct but needs an explanation for the newbies like me. security group ID for e.g. sg-df1b54b (and not the IP address like 3.215.4.45/32) should be added to inbound rule. I did not know a group ID can (or should as in this case) be added !!